# Installed Ubuntu 20.04 on Laptop (lenovo).Built in speaker doest not work. Only headset works

Tags: laptop

Pulseaudio volume control application shows Speakers(unavailable).
But, `lspci` command shows:

`Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 02c8`

Comment: Could you update your question to include some actionable information, such as which model of Lenovo you're using? The `lspci` snippet you shared seems to be incomplete, as there is an additional 5 characters that should be part of the device ID. Could you include the full output of `lspci` to ensure that the person who answers your question can offer something that isn't speculation? Help us help you 

Comment: lspci output: 00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 02c8

Comment: 00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 02c8 (prog-if 80)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Device 5079
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 64, IRQ 146
 Memory at b131c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
 Memory at b1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
 Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci

Comment: pls help how to proceed. I tried installing windows and speaker is working perfect. So, hardware seems to be fine.